# How find large files with QDirStat on Android 11 with root?

Tags: root-access, file-system, magisk, ssh, termux

I want to list all files in my phones `/data` volume using [QDirStat](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat#readme), or something simular.
On my phone, I've used [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1) ([`com.google.android.diskusage`](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.google.android.diskusage/)) before, but I find the visualization lacking.

I want to apply the steps described in this guide with my phone as the remote server:
https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/QDirStat-for-Servers.md

#### Technical details

- OnePlus phone running Android 11
- Root via Magisk
- SSH server with key-files
- GNU/Linux desktop PC
- Working SFTP mount of my phones `/` (FS root) on my  PC

#### Goals

- Create a reading on-device using the [QDirStat server script](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/QDirStat-for-Servers.md)

  - Run the script (folder & file indexer) on-device
  - Don't index from the PC via an SFTP mount
  - The script is headless: it does not contain a GUI
- Index every file & folder in `/data` (as root)
- Import the index-dump into QDirStat on my PC

  - Analyze the index on PC
  - Manually delete some files using Nautilus' SFTP

#### Questions

- The script seems to require Perl

  - How can Perl be installed on Android?
  - If it's installed in Termux, can it index everything?
  - What would be the (most-)proper way of doing this be?
- Can I run QDirStat on an ARM arch?

  - Will cross-compilation be required?
  - Will cross-compiling the Qt framework be required?
  - How do I provide the required libs for QDirStat?

---

Thanks for reading

Comment: Compiling QDirStat for ARM is not the problem, the main problem is that there is no X-Window system so you have to port the application to Android: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/porting-to-android.html Unless you have experience with QT I don't think this will be easy.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Robert; please note that the script is headless (edited the question to clear that up), meaning it doesn't have a GUI. (Quote: QDirStat can be used for headless (no X server, no X libs) servers) from [here](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/QDirStat-for-Servers.md#executive-summary)

Comment: Run the `qdirstat-cache-writer` script with root on Termux. Forget about running QT application on Android. For those who are comfortable with CLI, [`du`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) + [`sort`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) is great. For Android GUI lovers, SD Maid is a good app for storage analysis and cleaning.